# Unhide or return selected options on multiple select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, multiple-instances

Guys I'm creating a code that will remove a selected option on the other dropdown once selected, I used jQuery (jquery-1.10.1.min) but I don't know how will I be able to return the chosen option or number once the user change their mind.

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my script:

**HTML**

```
<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order1">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order2">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order3">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order4">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#question_order1').on('change', function() {
   var val=this.value; 
   $("#question_order2").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();     
   $("#question_order3").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
   $("#question_order4").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();

 });

$('#question_order2').on('change', function() {
  var val=this.value;
   $("#question_order1").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
   $("#question_order3").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
   $("#question_order4").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();

});

$('#question_order3').on('change', function() {
  var val=this.value;
   $("#question_order1").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
   $("#question_order2").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();     
   $("#question_order4").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();   
});


$('#question_order4').on('change', function() {
  var val=this.value;
   $("#question_order1").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();
   $("#question_order2").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();     
   $("#question_order3").find("option:contains("+val+")").remove();   
});


});//]]>
```

Comment: instead of removing them use `display:none` to hide them from user and have a refresh button to `display:block` all the hidden items.

Comment: The refresh button will be a problem though, since they want to show the data at once. Is it possible to show the value without any refresh?

Comment: Else how will you know the user is going to change his mind?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p9cpS/27/

Comment: @KawineshSK you can't hide options in IE, not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that first stores a copy of the `<option>` html. On change of a `<selecct>` it creates an array of all the selected values . It then rebuilds all the other ones from the stored html and filters the values allowed.

```
$(function () {
    var $quest = $('.question_order');
    /* cache option html */
    var optHtml = $quest.first().html();

    $quest.on('change', function () {
        /* make array of all selected values*/
        var selecteds=$quest.find('option:selected').map(function(){
            if(this.value){
               return this.value 
            }
        }).get();
        /* rebuild the other select elements*/
        $quest.not(this).each(function(){
            var selVal=this.value || '';
            /* create new set of options with filtered values*/ 
            var $opts=$(optHtml).filter(function(){
                return $.inArray(this.value,selecteds) ==-1 ||  this.value ==selVal
            });
            /* replace children*/
           $(this).html($opts).val(selVal);

        });
    });

});
```

Note that `class="question_order"` added to each element.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mKPQS/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order1" >
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order2" >
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order3" >
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>

<select name="question_order[]" id="question_order4" >
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9cpS/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it not working, the problem is when a user choose option 1 on the first select, then option 2 on the 2nd select and option 3 on the third select, but they suddenly changed their mind and choose 1 on 2nd select and 2 on the first select, my problem is that I need to show the remaining selection on the third select in case they change the first select to 3.