# jQuery multiple Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to find a good way to synchronise multiple drop downs. I have seen code that does it for two drop downs but I need it to work across 3 or more. Is there an elegant way to do this. The code below does not work for three drop downs (*only two*) but is the closest example I could find.

I am trying to make it so that if any of the drop downs changes that selected option in that drop down is no longer available in the other drop downs.

### HTML

```
<!-- 1st DropDown: -->
    <select name="d1" id="d1">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

<!-- 2nd DropDown: -->
    <select name="d2" id="d2">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

<!-- 3nd DropDown: -->
    <select name="d3" id="d3">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#d1').change(function(e) {
   index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
   $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                    .css('display','block');

   $('#d3 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                    .css('display','block');
});

$('#d2').change(function(e) {
  index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $('#d1 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                   .css('display','block');

  $('#d3 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                   .css('display','block');
});

$('#d3').change(function(e) {
  index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $('#d1 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                   .css('display','block');

  $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings()
                                   .css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: few browsers support `display:none` on `<option>` tag. IE certinly does not

Comment: see solution I provided in this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20419266/1175966  Appears to be exactly what you want

Comment: Are you trying to hide individual option tags or the actual select drop down? Your code is trying to hide individual option tags which just won't work.